# Alladin eToken failure with importing RSA key

Tags: c#, rsa, pkcs#11, e-token

I am using SafeNet's (Alladin) eToken with PKCS11 interface to C#.
I need to import a RSA key created without the eToken into the eToken.

The creation of the RSA key is done through:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters publicKey = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
RSAParameters privateKey = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
eTokenHelper.WritePrivateKeyToToken(session, privateKey, "private");
```

and the implementation of the WritePrivateKeyToToken above is:

```
public static void WritePrivateKeyToToken(PKCS11.Session session, System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters publicParams, string label)
    {

        List<PKCS11.Attribute> attList = new List<PKCS11.Attribute>{};


        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_CLASS, PKCS11.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_KEY_TYPE, PKCS11.CKK_RSA));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_PRIVATE, true));
        //attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_SUBJECT, cert.SubjectName.RawData));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_ID, 0xa1));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_LABEL, label));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_TOKEN, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_MODULUS, publicParams.Modulus));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, publicParams.Exponent));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_PRIVATE_EXPONENT, publicParams.D));
        // attList.Add(new ObjectAttribute(PKCS11.CKH_CLOCK, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_MODIFIABLE, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_LOCAL, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_EXTRACTABLE, false));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_NEVER_EXTRACTABLE, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_SENSITIVE, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_ALWAYS_SENSITIVE, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_DERIVE, false));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_LOCAL, false));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_DECRYPT, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_SIGN, true));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_SIGN_RECOVER, false));
        attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_UNWRAP, false));

        PKCS11.Object.Create(session, attList.ToArray());
    }
```

when I run this code, I get the exception with code

```
public const int CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT = 0x000000D1;
```

(the exception appears on the last line: Create()).

I will appreciate any assistance in understandin what am I doing wrong.

Thanks,
Ronen

Answer (score 3):

I have some problem. By the way, you set atribut PKCS11.CKA_LOCAL twice in the code. It is not corect.  Do not set attribute PKCS11.CKA_LOCAL - it is set automatically. If is set PKCS11.SENSITIVE, it is not possible to set CKA_EXTRACTABLE, CKA_NEVER_EXTRACTABLE and CKA_ALWAYS_SENSITIVE.

This code should work:

```
   List<PKCS11.Attribute> attList = new List<PKCS11.Attribute>{};

    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_CLASS, PKCS11.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_KEY_TYPE, PKCS11.CKK_RSA));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_PRIVATE, true));
    //attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_SUBJECT, cert.SubjectName.RawData));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_ID, 0xa1));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_LABEL, label));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_TOKEN, true));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_MODULUS, publicParams.Modulus));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, publicParams.Exponent));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_PRIVATE_EXPONENT, publicParams.D));
    // attList.Add(new ObjectAttribute(PKCS11.CKH_CLOCK, true));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_MODIFIABLE, true));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_SENSITIVE, true));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_DERIVE, false));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_DECRYPT, true));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_SIGN, true));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_SIGN_RECOVER, false));
    attList.Add(new PKCS11.Attribute(PKCS11.CKA_UNWRAP, false));

    PKCS11.Object.Create(session, attList.ToArray());
```

Comment: Jiri, thanks for the answer... from the long distance of the passed time, can you figure out why I'm getting `public const int CKR_TEMPLATE_INCOMPLETE = 0x000000D0;` with your code? any help will be appreciate!